# Semi-robust newspaper column extraction

Tags: c++, opencv

This is my first openCV program, so be forgiving if I seem ignorant to some basic computer vision concepts.

**UPDATE:** See new code/new problem at bottom thanks to the answer by [sturkmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215893/2813411)

I am working on "digitizing" a large set of images, like the ones attached, as a project. All images come from the same source. The end goal is to pass extracted chunks of text to tesseract, the OCR library.

**(Source code at bottom)**
I am going to explain my current approach, and then state my questions.

My current approach is as follows:

1. Apply inverse binary threshold
2. Dilate image and find contours  [image]
3. Create a `boundingRect` from each contour, then filter for minimum and maximum dimensions

This has worked *ok*

[image]

My desired end result is to have one `boundingRect` around each column. So for the provided pictures that would be seven of them.

So, the problem is that the tabulated "mini sections" in the image are not reliably picked up (best example would be the one in the far right column that does not have a `boundingRect` around it).

I can think of two possible solutions (so as to not be an open-ended / opinion type question) but if you know of a better solution do share it!

**1)** combine `boundingRect`s that are vertical neighbors to capture the columns. Contains possible edge-case failures.

**2)** Find a different way to manipulate the image before finding the contours. From my research, the run length smoothing algorithm looks promising?

So my question is, which approach is best? Have I overlooked a better solution? I am inexperienced in this department, so no suggestion is too small.

Thanks for reading!

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread(path_to_file);
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat fin;
    double thresh = threshold(gray, fin, 160, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    //size impacts dilation
    Mat kernel =  getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(2, 4));
    Mat dilated;
    dilate(fin, dilated, kernel, Point(-1,-1), 6);
    imwrite("testbw.png",dilated);
    Mat hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >contours;
    findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //potentially sort by x
    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
         //       x     y
        //columns 850 x 5400
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);
        if (r.height > 3000 || r.width > 875)
            continue;
        if (r.height < 100 || r.width < 500)
            continue;

        rectangle(image, r, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2); //made thicker
    }
    imwrite("test.png", image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

}

Original Image: [image]

**Updated code**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread(path_to_file);
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat fin;
    double thresh = threshold(gray, fin, 160, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Mat kernel =  getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(2, 4));
    Mat dilated;
    dilate(fin, dilated, kernel, Point(-1,-1), 6);
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >contours;
    findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Rect> rects;
    Rect big_rect = Rect(image.cols/2,image.rows/2,1,1);

    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
        //        x     y
        //columns 850 x 5400
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);
        if (r.height > 5500 || r.width > 875)
            continue;
        if (r.height < 300 || r.width < 500)
            continue;

        big_rect = big_rect | r; // here we will find bounding box of all Rects
        rects.push_back( r ); // stores rects 
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        // sets y and height of all rects 
        //cout << rects[i].x << endl;
        rects[i].y = big_rect.y;
        rects[i].height = big_rect.height;
    }

    //groupRectangles(rects, 1); DIDN'T WORK

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        rectangle(image, rects[i], Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    }
    imshow("test", image);
```

New Result: [image]

New Problem: There are many `boundingRect`s around each column (you probably can't tell by looking at the picture). This is a problem, because I want to make a sub-image of each column e.g. `Mat ROI = image(rects[i])` which would render much more than the desired 7 images.

New Question: How can I combine the multitude of rectangles per column, into one? I have seen openCV's `groupRectangles`, but it failed to work.

Comment: What I want is one `boundingRect` per column. But a solution that reliably captured the tabulated squares would also work. I initially presumed it would be easiest to have one `boundingRect` per column, that would contain just that column. Because from there I will create (in this case 7) sub images (one per column) then pass those to tesseract for OCR. I'll work on uploading original image now

Comment: Do you need a method that clusters the rectangles you have right now into 7 columns? Or something that directly detect the full columns?

Comment: That is where I am open to suggestions, sorry if that isn't very helpful. Which would you choose? As long as I can reliably capture nearly every word in the image, my goal is achieved. I think that if the rectangles were clustered vertically (so as to seperate columns) then there would be edge-cases where it would fail, that I mention in the question.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit and try and be more clear. Thanks for the suggestion! Also, I'll add my code

Comment: @Miki Right! I'm looking for an image hosting service that can handle an 18MB file. Imgur did not like it. Will comment when I get it up

Comment: @Miki Added the original image

Comment: "How can I combine the multitude of rectangles per column, into one?" As they all overlap, partition by distance of their centers and then merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to show a method i tried to change your code as below.

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat fin;
    double thresh = threshold(gray, fin, 160, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    //size impacts dilation
    Mat kernel =  getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(2, 4));
    Mat dilated;
    dilate(fin, dilated, kernel, Point(-1,-1), 1);
    imwrite("testbw.png",dilated);
    Mat hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >contours;
    findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Rect> rects;
    Rect big_rect = Rect(image.cols/2,image.rows/2,1,1);
    //potentially sort by x
    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
        //       x     y
        //columns 850 x 5400
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);
        if (r.height > 3000 || r.width > 875)
            continue;
        if (r.height < 10 || r.width < 10) // changed for test small image
            continue;

        big_rect = big_rect | r; // here we will find bounding box of all Rects
        rects.push_back( r ); // stores rects 
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        // sets y and height of all rects 
        rects[i].y = big_rect.y;
        rects[i].height = big_rect.height;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        rectangle(image, rects[i], Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    imshow("result", image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Test Image]
[image]

i know it is incomplete but i hope you will understand the way and complete it by filtering the rects to find desired seven rect or i will complete the code soon.

EDIT:  the code maybe a bit dirty but `vector<Rect> final_rects` contains only the rects you need.

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct sorter_func
{
    bool operator ()( Rect a, Rect b )
    {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat fin;
    double thresh = threshold(gray, fin, 160, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    //size impacts dilation
    Mat kernel =  getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size(2, 4));
    Mat dilated;
    dilate(fin, dilated, kernel, Point(-1,-1), 1);
    imwrite("testbw.png",dilated);
    Mat hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >contours;
    findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Rect> rects;
    Rect big_rect = Rect(image.cols/2,image.rows/2,1,1);
    //potentially sort by x
    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
        //       x     y
        //columns 850 x 5400
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);
        if (r.height > 3000 || r.width > 875)
            continue;
        if (r.height < 10 || r.width < 10) // changed for test small image
            continue;

        big_rect = big_rect | r; // here we will find bounding box of all Rects
        rects.push_back( r ); // stores rects
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        // sets y and height of all rects
        rects[i].y = big_rect.y;
        rects[i].height = big_rect.height;
    }

    std::sort(rects.begin(), rects.end(), sorter_func());

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        Rect big_rect = rects[i-1] | rects[i];
        if( big_rect.width < rects[i-1].width + rects[i].width )
        {
            rects[i-1] = Rect();
            rects[i] = big_rect;
        }
    }

    vector<Rect> final_rects;
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < rects.size(); i++ )
    {
        if( rects[i].width > 0 )
        {
            rectangle(image, rects[i], Scalar(rand()&255,rand()&255,rand()&255), 2);
            final_rects.push_back( rects[i] );
            cerr << final_rects.size() << endl;
        }
    }
    imshow("result", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! This seems to be a great approach. I had adapted your code a little last night, and it wraps the columns perfectly, but I am battling one thing.. There are many (probably around 5-10) `boundingRect`s around each column. So I'll need to eliminate all but one, because my plan is to make a sub-image from each `boundingRect`. I'll update my question

Comment: @Trés DuBiel i updated the code. let me know if you need some help to understand the code.

Comment: very nice! I came to a separate solution with the same result, but I like yours better! Seems more robust. I think I get the idea of your code, I'll try and summarize it. You sort the rects in ascending order (by x value), the bitwise OR `|` I can't quite wrap my head around but the result of it leaves only the largest `Rect` per column, leaving the smaller `Rect`s per column equal to `Rect()`. Then from there you filter out all `Rects` that have no `width`. If you have the time, explain the `|` operation a bit.

Comment: you can find related documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html) ( also i would like to see your solution.)

Comment: `rect = rect1 | rect2` (minimum area rectangle containing rect1 and rect2 )

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks a ton

Comment: Oh, I did not see where you asked to see my solution. I had two, but only one worked perfectly. The one that worked was, in fact, `groupRectangles` but I had to play with the values for it to work, and it might not have been robust across a set of ~1000 similar images. So your approach is better, I would think

Comment: I hope that the project will be successful. i am always ready to help to smart programmers as you. Because i learn and do practise.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment, thank you. You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/dubielt1/Article-extraction): it works great!!